# conditionally remove leading or trailing `.` character in R

Tags: r, regex

I have a vector of names where some names have leading and trailing `.` characters, and some do not. Here is an example:

```
test <- c('.name.1.','name.2','.name.3.')
```

I would like to conditionally remove leading and trailing `.` characters in these names, to return

```
c('name.1','name.2','name.3')
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use regular expressions:

```
test <- c('.name.1.','name.2','.name.3.')
gsub('^\\.|\\.$', '', test)
# [1] "name.1" "name.2" "name.3"
```

The two backslashes, `\\`, in the regular expression escape the dot, `.`, which would actually mean any character. The caret, `^`, marks the beginning of the string, the dollar, `$`, the end of the string. The pipe, `|`, is a logical "or". So in essence the regular expression matches a dot at the beginning of the string or a dot at the end of the string and replaces it with an empty string.

More information on regular expressions can be found [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/regex.html) and information on gsub and related functions [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/grep.html).

Answer (score 3):

A quick function using the `substr` function:

```
fun1 <- function(x) substr(x, 1 + (1 * as.numeric(substr(x,1,1)=='.')), nchar(x) - (1 * as.numeric(substr(x, nchar(x), nchar(x)) == '.')))
```

We use `substr` to check for a `.` in the first and last elements of the string, then we use `substr` again to extract certain parts of the text. For example, if there is a `.` in the first character, but not in the second, we'll extract: `substr(text, 2, nchar(text))`.

```
fun1(test)
[1] "name.1" "name.2" "name.3"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `str_extract` from `stringr`:

```
library(stringr)

str_extract(test, "\\w+\\.\\d")
```

or `str_replace_all` (`stringr`-equivalent to `gsub`):

```
str_replace_all(test, "[.](.+)[.]", "\\1")

# [1] "name.1" "name.2" "name.3"
```

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun, here is a method with `substring` and `grepl`.

```
substring(test, 1L + grepl("^\\.", test), nchar(test) - grepl("\\.$", test))
[1] "name.1" "name.2" "name.3"
```

This will work replacing `substring` with `substr`. The cool thing about these functions is that they take vectors for their second and third arguments. Here, we can use `grepl` to increment between 1L and 2L for the second argument and between the position of the final character and the penultimate character.