# Remove trailing "/'

Tags: r

One of the columns contains data in the form of web URLs. At the end of some of those URLs is a "/" and I need to remove it, but not touch other "/" that may be present elsewhere in the URL.

I tired gsub, but that is a slippery slope because it will just remove all "/" marks. I need to remove at the end of the URL only.

```
#read in IIS logfile
logfile = "u_ex190510.log"
logcols = read.table(logfile, header = FALSE, 
                      sep = " ", skip = 3, nrows = 1, comment.char = "")
iislog = read.table(logfile, header = FALSE, sep = " ",comment.char = "#")
logcols[,1] <- NULL
names(iislog) <- unlist(logcols[1,])
View(iislog)
#rename the columns
colnames(iislog)= c('date','time','sourceIP','csMethod','csUriStem',
                    'csUriQuery','sourcePort','csUsername','clientIP','userAgent','csReferer',
                    'scStatus','scSubstatus','scWin32Status','timeTaken')
#load libraries used for date changes and sorting
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
#change data type for date and time columns
iislog$date <- ymd(iislog$date)
iislog$time <- hms(iislog$time)
#create subset of the original data
iislog1 <- iislog %>% select(date,time,csUriStem,timeTaken)
#ensure the csUriStem column is in all lowercase. This is because the URLs
#sem to have mixed case and therefore can show up moe than once.
iislog1$csUriStem <- tolower(iislog1$csUriStem)
iislog1
#Find unique URLs by grouping.
iislog2 <- iislog1 %>% group_by(csUriStem) %>% summarise(count=n())
#arrange the results by csUriStem. It would be nice to do this in ascending order.
iislog3 <- arrange(iislog2,desc(csUriStem), .by_group=TRUE)
iislog3
```

Comment: Have you checked [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46671796/conditionally-remove-leading-or-trailing-character-in-r/46672008)

Comment: In regex, `$` is used to mark the end of the string. So, `gsub("/$", "", your_input)`.

Comment: As an aside, most of the code you share seems irrelevant to your question. Moreover, you don't have any sample input. It would be a much better question if it was focused on the issue, something like "*I have URLs, like this: `x <- c("http://www.google.com/", "http://sample.com/url/with/many/slashes/", "http://www.somedontendinslashes.com")`, and I need to remove the slashes from the end. I tried `gsub("/", "", x)` but it remove all the slashes, and I need to keep the slashes in the middle."*

Comment: new to StackOverflow, so thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```
my.url <- "http://test.test/test.test.html/"
gsub("/$", "", my.url)
```

it returns

```
[1] "http://test.test/test.test.html"
```

you can use `$` to look for elements at the end of the line

Comment: Thanks for the info, I am also quite new here :-)

Comment: To keep with the tidyverse way of doing things same outcome can be done with `str_replace` from the `stringr` package, still using the '$' to anchor removing at the end of line

`library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(url = "http://test.test/test.test.html/")

df <- df %>% 
  mutate(new_url = str_remove(url, '/$') )`

Comment: Now, similarly, I have another log file that has a "?" somewhere in the URL string. I want to find the ? and then remove all the text after it. I thought of using something like this,but did not work. appInsights$url <- gsub("^\\?.*", "", appInsights$url)

Comment: @Vegas588 `^` means the start of the string, so `"^\\?.*"` only matches a question mark right at the start. I think you just want `"\\?.*`.

Comment: Alfonso, why `gsub()` and not `sub()`?