# How to split these ingredients that are followed by a different numbers of abbreviations within brackets

Tags: r, regex, string, strsplit

Here is an excerpt of what my data looks like:

"glyphosate (HBC), atrazine (HBC), metam potassium (FUN, HBC, INS, NEM), dichloropropene (HBC, NEM), metolachlor(-s) (HBC), chlorothalonil (FUN), chloropicrin (NEM), bacillus amyloliquifacien (FUN), 2,4-d (HBC, PGR)"

I want this example to look like this:

[image: Split data]

I know all the possible abbreviations (HBC, FUN etc) if that helps.

This is what I have tried so far.

```
str = "glyphosate (HBC), atrazine (HBC), dichloropropene (HBC, NEM), metolachlor(-s) (HBC), chlorothalonil (FUN), chloropicrin (NEM), bacillus amyloliquifacien (FUN), 2,4-d (HBC, PGR), pendimethalin (HBC), metam (FUN, HBC, INS, NEM), acetochlor (HBC), metribuzin (HBC), dicamba (HBC), phorate (INS), chlorpyrifos (ACA, INS), flutolanil (FUN), paraquat (HBC), propazine (HBC), dimethenamid(-p) (HBC, FUN), bromoxynil (HBC)"

vec = unlist(unlist(strsplit(str, " ()")))
vec_clean = gsub('^\\(|\\),|\\,|)$', '', vec)

matrix(vec_clean,nrow = 24,ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
```

Which gives me:

```
> matrix(vec_clean,nrow = 24,ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
      [,1]               [,2]             
 [1,] "glyphosate"       "HBC"            
 [2,] "atrazine"         "HBC"            
 [3,] "dichloropropene"  "HBC"            
 [4,] "NEM"              "metolachlor(-s" 
 [5,] "HBC"              "chlorothalonil" 
 [6,] "FUN"              "chloropicrin"   
 [7,] "NEM"              "bacillus"       
 [8,] "amyloliquifacien" "FUN"            
 [9,] "24-d"             "HBC"            
[10,] "PGR"              "pendimethalin"  
[11,] "HBC"              "metam"          
[12,] "FUN"              "HBC"            
[13,] "INS"              "NEM"            
[14,] "acetochlor"       "HBC"            
[15,] "metribuzin"       "HBC"            
[16,] "dicamba"          "HBC"            
[17,] "phorate"          "INS"            
[18,] "chlorpyrifos"     "ACA"            
[19,] "INS"              "flutolanil"     
[20,] "FUN"              "paraquat"       
[21,] "HBC"              "propazine"      
[22,] "HBC"              "dimethenamid(-p"
[23,] "HBC"              "FUN"            
[24,] "bromoxynil"       "HBC"
```

The argument I use in str split " ()" was due to trial and error and I don't understand exactly why this works to some extent. I tried removing the leading and trailing "(" and ",)" using an example that I modified from here:
[conditionally remove leading or trailing `.` character in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46671796/conditionally-remove-leading-or-trailing-character-in-r/46672008)

So it is a start but when an ingredient har more abbreviations e.g. (FUN, HBC etc) it also splits it there. It also removes the "," from 2,4-d and from between abrreviations which it shouldn't. It removes the trailing ")" from dimethenamid(-p) which it also shouldn't.

Comment: "dichloropropene (HBC, NEM)" is missing from the image of the table you want.

Answer (score 0):

Using `stringr::str_match_all`

```
stringr::str_match_all(str, ",?\\s?(.*?)\\s\\((.*?)\\),")[[1]][, -1]

#       [,1]                        [,2]                
# [1,] "glyphosate"                "HBC"               
# [2,] "atrazine"                  "HBC"               
# [3,] "dichloropropene"           "HBC, NEM"          
# [4,] "metolachlor(-s)"           "HBC"               
# [5,] "chlorothalonil"            "FUN"               
# [6,] "chloropicrin"              "NEM"               
# [7,] "bacillus amyloliquifacien" "FUN"               
# [8,] "2,4-d"                     "HBC, PGR"          
# [9,] "pendimethalin"             "HBC"               
#[10,] "metam"                     "FUN, HBC, INS, NEM"
#[11,] "acetochlor"                "HBC"               
#[12,] "metribuzin"                "HBC"               
#[13,] "dicamba"                   "HBC"               
#[14,] "phorate"                   "INS"               
#[15,] "chlorpyrifos"              "ACA, INS"          
#[16,] "flutolanil"                "FUN"               
#[17,] "paraquat"                  "HBC"               
#[18,] "propazine"                 "HBC"               
#[19,] "dimethenamid(-p)"          "HBC, FUN"
```

We extract two parts from each value. First part starts with an optional comma and whitespace (for 2nd value onwards) until an opening round bracket is encountered (`(`) and second part is everything inside opening and closing round brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R solution:

```r
str = "glyphosate (HBC), atrazine (HBC), dichloropropene (HBC, NEM), metolachlor(-s) (HBC), chlorothalonil (FUN), chloropicrin (NEM), bacillus amyloliquifacien (FUN), 2,4-d (HBC, PGR), pendimethalin (HBC), metam (FUN, HBC, INS, NEM), acetochlor (HBC), metribuzin (HBC), dicamba (HBC), phorate (INS), chlorpyrifos (ACA, INS), flutolanil (FUN), paraquat (HBC), propazine (HBC), dimethenamid(-p) (HBC, FUN), bromoxynil (HBC)"
out <- strsplit(str, "(?<=\\)), ", perl=TRUE)[[1]]
out <- strsplit(out, "( \\()|(\\)$)", perl=TRUE)
do.call(rbind, out)
#>       [,1]                        [,2]                
#>  [1,] "glyphosate"                "HBC"               
#>  [2,] "atrazine"                  "HBC"               
#>  [3,] "dichloropropene"           "HBC, NEM"          
#>  [4,] "metolachlor(-s)"           "HBC"               
#>  [5,] "chlorothalonil"            "FUN"               
#>  [6,] "chloropicrin"              "NEM"               
#>  [7,] "bacillus amyloliquifacien" "FUN"               
#>  [8,] "2,4-d"                     "HBC, PGR"          
#>  [9,] "pendimethalin"             "HBC"               
#> [10,] "metam"                     "FUN, HBC, INS, NEM"
#> [11,] "acetochlor"                "HBC"               
#> [12,] "metribuzin"                "HBC"               
#> [13,] "dicamba"                   "HBC"               
#> [14,] "phorate"                   "INS"               
#> [15,] "chlorpyrifos"              "ACA, INS"          
#> [16,] "flutolanil"                "FUN"               
#> [17,] "paraquat"                  "HBC"               
#> [18,] "propazine"                 "HBC"               
#> [19,] "dimethenamid(-p)"          "HBC, FUN"          
#> [20,] "bromoxynil"                "HBC"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>